# Intento instalar rails en ubuntu pero surge un error de permisos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Buen dia, alguien me podria ayudar, estoy intentando instalar rails con el comando gem install rails en ubuntu 20, pero arroja este error: You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.7.0 directory.

muchas gracias por su atencion.

Comment: Prueba a instalar mejor un administrador de versiones como `rbenv` o `rvm` y desde ahí instala ruby y rails sin tener que entrar a modificar carpetas del sistema.

Comment: lo intentare, michas gracias.